# Spring Boot Get Value of object from select using thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

So I have this project, and I want to return an object, from the previous choice of 2 select items. How can I do it? for example:

```
<select class="form-control" id="cityPicker1">
        <option value="0">select option</option>
        <option th:each="city: ${listCities}" th:value="${city.number}" th:text="${city.name}"></option>
    </select>
    
    <select class="form-control" id="cityPicker2">
        <option value="0">select option</option>
        <option th:each="city: ${listCities}" th:value="${city.number}" th:text="${city.name}"></option>
    </select>
```

I want to display an item from another item list which has a number1 field and a number2 something like ticket.number1 and ticket.number2 but they have to match the values from the previous selects. I can't seem to find anything. Any ideas?

This is how I set it up in the controller:

```
@GetMapping("/tickets")
public String viewTicketsPage(Model model) {
    List<City> listCities = cityRepo.findAll();
    List<Ticket> listTickets = ticketRepo.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("listCities", listCities);
    model.addAttribute("listTickets", listTickets);
    return "tickets";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to clarify a few things about your question.
1 - did you manage to get the checkboxes to work?
2 - can you send the selected data to the controller?

you need a controller to receive data from the page, send this data to the repository to fetch other data..

I believe you want to select a table, where the data matches the selected ones. .

take a look at JPQL, maybe this will help you:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

Comment: Hello and thank you for answering. How would I be able to write the value I took from the page inside the quary? I am trying now to get the value from the select using POST method but I usually get a 405 post is forbidden. I don't really know how to do it and the tutorials i found are not clear

Comment: do you want to get a list of tickets from two selected cities?